# Are there any way to create a freeform entity

Tags: entity, dialogflow-es

I am trying to capture a description for a user problem so we can log that with a bot. Are there any sys entity that can do that or is there a way to create an entity that can capture any random sentence the user enters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [@sys.any](https://api.ai/docs/reference/system-entities#generic).  @sys.any captures any value.  Be careful with this system entity and be sure to give very good user says examples when using @sys.any or you can end up with unhelpful input.